# Clickhouse : remove duplicate data

Tags: clickhouse

i have a problem with duplicate data in clickhouse.
my case is i have records come in parts then i have to group all these parts by text_id.
The arrival time of the parts may be at different times

for example :

```
id,text_id,total_parts,part_number,text
101,11,3,1,How
102,12,2,2,World
103,12,2,1,Hello
104,11,3,3,you
105,11,3,2,are
```

and the result should be like this :

```
text_id,text
11, How are you
12, Hello World
```

i create a **view** to group all parts and it's working fine.
but when i read from this **view** i want to remove the rows that i already read. I tried to add a column to the table called flag then update this column to 1 then change the view to read flag = 0.
but i read in clickhouse docs that update it decrease the performance. and my table has **billions** of records.

1- the view will be slow if i can't remove the processed records.

2- If there is no performance issue in view i don't want to read the processed data again.

any suggestion?

Comment: I would return the additional field *max(id) max_id* in view result to store it on the server-side. And pass this *max_id* to a query to restrict the scope of the search.

Answer (score 0):

The closest result you can is arrays of text column:

```
SELECT groupArray(text) as msg
FROM 
  (SELECT * ROM merge_rows ORDER BY text_id, part_number) 
GRUP BY text_id

┌─msg─────────────────┐
│ ['Hello','World']   │
│ ['How','are','you'] │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Since you have **billions** of rows, integrating into materialized views will do it really fast.